Get tables from AWS Glue using boto3 and create dataframe
I am trying to create Spark data frame from the below tables.
glueclient = boto3.client('glue',region_name='xyz')

def readtable(catalog:str,database:str):

     response = glueclient.get_tables(Databasename=database)

     for tables in response['TableList']:

         tablename=tables['Name']

         par_loc=response['Table']['StorageDescriptor']['Loaction']
         return spark.read.parquet(par_loc)
    

Getting error as parameter validation failed.
Any help is highly appreciated?

Parameter names are case-sensitive, i.e. you need to do
response = glueclient.get_tables(DatabaseName=database)

But i dont think this solves the  the above problem.
